# React Native Button. Logo on the left and the rest is the text

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, flexbox, position

```js
const Button = ({  onPress, children, fontColor='black', backgroundColor='white', fontSize, url,borderRadius=7, style}) => {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          paddingVertical: 10,
          paddingHorizontal: 10,
          borderRadius: borderRadius,
          justifyContent: url ? 'flex-start' : 'center',
          alignItems:'center',
        },
        image:{
            borderWidth:2,
            borderColor:"#000",

            height:"100%",
            width:"100%",
            flex:1,
        },
        text: {
          borderWidth:2,
          borderColor:"#0000ff",

          color: fontColor,
          fontSize: fontSize,
          marginLeft: url ? 10 : 0,
          textAlign:"center"
        },
      });

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.container, style]} onPress={onPress}>
      {url && <Image source={url} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.image}/>}
      <Text style={styles.text} adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}>{children}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Hello,

[image]

As you can see on the picture above, i have a logo and a text on a button. I would like that the logo fit to the button as it's already the case on the image (the size). And i would have it on the left that it take the less place as possible. As you can see on the picture, it's not the case and it take empty space which reduce the space of the text. The "SMS" is completely push on the right because the box of the image not fit to the new scale picture.

[image]

There we can see that it's not due to the image itself.

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little to make it work on my system.

By understanding your requirement I think you were expecting some like this.

[image]

To achieve this you have to wrap your `Image` in a `View` and give it defined `width` and `height` rather than giving it a `100%`.
Also, make sure to add `justifyContent` set to `space-between` in the parent wrap.

```
import {
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}> // Add this container for image
          <Image
            src={'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png'}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={styles.image}
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Test</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between', // add this prop
  },
  image: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  text: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#0000ff',
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '50%',
  },
  imageContainer: { 
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#000',
  },
});
```

Check the snack [here.](https://snack.expo.dev/Aj5zxs1zSpdmpe_HnDjq8)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. Adding value size for the image it's what i didn't wanted to do. The goal is that the image set automatically to the good size depending of it's container the button.